# SSL setup on webserver

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

first foray into getting SSL up and running on my web server.  Apache running fine on port 80, but I want to start securing things more and running https.

I generated my server key, and then produced a CSR for the domain.  That all worked fine, and I got sent back:
www_mydomain_com.crt
and a folder called "RootCertificates" containing two more .crt, a RootCertificate and an IntermediateCertificate.crt

Now my (clearly incorrect!) thinking was I needed to add a virtual host to my ssl.conf file along these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:143>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/www_mydomain_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/RootCertificates/IntermediateCertificate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the ssl.conf already has some of those lines included - should I be commenting those out?

Apologies - I've been looking at this all day and have confused myself somewhat :)

Comment: 1. Why are you using port 143 instead of 443? 2. Config looks fine. What happens if you start your server? There may be one pitfall: If you insist on using port 143 you might have to add the statement `listen 143` somewhere.

Comment: What a muppet!! Naturally changing 143 to 443 sorted things straight away (nearly!).  I simply had to change <VirtualHost *:443> to <VirtualHost server-ip:443> and we were up and running - thank you!!

Comment: Follow up question...where would I use RootCertificate.crt as opposed to IntermediateCertifciate.crt? Is there a right and a wrong to use? Thank you!